# Cannot detect timeout error from server api or client code ? Test with nodejs vs postman

Tags: node.js, npm, request, postman

I faced a problem that I cannot detect where it was, from server api or from my client code ?
API is product of my partner, so I cannot debug it, too.
If you've ever encountered an error like this, I'm grateful for your sharing.
Many thanks.

Here is my Postman request, evey requests was ok, got return as expected
[image]

Here is my simple code to make http post, got timeout error

[image]

got timeout error

```
{ Error: ETIMEDOUT
at Timeout.<anonymous> (F:\DEV\PROJECTS_IONIC\api\node_modules\request\request.js:848:19)
at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)
at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)
at listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5)
at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10) code: 'ETIMEDOUT', connect: true }
```

Comment: What header are you passing in the Postman request?

Comment: @Div: content-type: application/json...this is header of postman

Comment: @Div: I think there is some issues with server api, I've just tried again, my code executed and returned results too fast while postman was too slow. Thank for your help.